# Divide If In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a few pages I'm pulling from a SQL Query, I wanted to divide one cell by another cell like a SUMIF formula but dividing instead of summing.

I did try this formula but it didn't work.

> =IF(A2=Query1[item_number],'Reference Sheet'!B2/Query1[case_pack_quantity], "")

I'm trying to find how many pallets of product there are or at least in general and it's not working.

Comment: There's no attempt at division in your `IF` call. It's also rather unclear what you're asking. If you want to divide one cell by another cell, there's no need to use `IF` at all; it's a straight formula.

Comment: what are the values of: Query1[item_number]     ,   'Reference Sheet'!B2 and Query1[case_pack_quantity] ?

Comment: @KenWhite I was able to work around it,
@Andreas 
Here's a sample of the data I was using
Formulas For Off Site Sums Pallet Pallet Count
AA478 48 48 1
AA538 792 240 3.3
I did `SUMIF` off a master sheet to sum up all the inventory if they were the right item, then I did a `SUMIF` against a item profile for the pallet amount and then divided. the first against the second to see how many pallets they would equate to. I think there could be a way to nest these together but I'm not good enough in excel yet to do that.